# Is there a way to change back to "supersoldier" difficulty in Crysis 3 through the console?

Tags: crysis-3

I didn't realize it would lock me out of it if I turned the difficulty down. Is there a way to restore it back?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to change back to your previous difficulty.

Comment: Does this apply to difficulty settings in general?